# Leaflet addMarkers not rendered when using clusterOptions with addPolygons or addRasterImage

Tags: r, r-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a working leaflet map that shows several markers clustered using clusterOptions. 
I want to add topography data and some border shapefiles as a background instead of the default tiles.
However, addMarkers with clusterOptions is not rendered if addRasterImage (or addPolygons) is used on the same map.

Using addRasterImage in addition to addTiles, rather replacing addTiles with addRasterImage, renders the marker clusters properly. However, this is not a solution because I do not want to use tiles for aesthetic and resource reasons.

```
library(leaflet)

# this works
leaflet(quakes) %>% 
  setView( lat=-23, lng=180, zoom=6) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat)


# this doesn't work, only shows polygons... if anything
leaflet(quakes) %>% 
  setView( lat=-23, lng=180, zoom=6) %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, clusterOptions = TRUE) %>%
  addPolygons(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, fill = F, weight = 1.5, color = "gray", opacity = 0.9, fillOpacity = 0)


# this works (takes a while), but I don't want to use tiles :(
leaflet(quakes) %>% 
  setView( lat=-23, lng=180, zoom=6) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, clusterOptions = TRUE) %>%
  addPolygons(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, fill = F, weight = 1.5, color = "gray", opacity = 0.9, fillOpacity = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

THe issue is becaourse of the `clusterOptions = TRUE` options. If you remove it, the map works:

```
leaflet(quakes) %>% 
  setView( lat=-23, lng=180, zoom=6) %>%
  addPolygons(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, fill = F, weight = 1.5, color = "gray", opacity = 0.9, fillOpacity = 0) %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat)
```

I do not know why tiles are mandatory to enable this option but I guess it is related to the polygons are drawn to stablish cluster are mapped to a tile

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the fact that I want to use clusterOptions with addPolygons is the entire point of my post. I still need to find a solution.